'Permission denied' on volume bind in Podman container
I am trying to run a Podman container with a volume bind to a data directory on the host, where this data directory has limited permissions. Even though my user account has access, I get a 'permission denied' from inside the container.

The data directory /mnt/data is owned by a local group:
$ ls -lah /mnt
drwxrwx---      root  comp            data

My local user is a member of that group:
$ whoami
robert
$ groups
robert comp

And I can access /mnt/data as expected.
But now I try to access the folder though a rootless container:
podman run --rm -it -v /mnt/data:/mnt/data ubuntu

and I cannot get into the folder:
(container) # ls -lah /mnt/data
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/data/': Permission denied

Some closer inspection:
(container) # ls -lah /mnt
drwxrwx---    nobody nogroup     data
(container) # whoami
root
(container) # groups
root

Okay, according to this I wouldn't be able to access my data folder indeed (assuming root in the container is not a real superuser).

How can I let the correct permissions apply inside the container too?

The Podman documentation hasn't helped me yet: https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-run.1.html
There is also How can I solve a Permission denied error to a mounted volume when running a podman pod?, which suggests --userns=keep-id, but this doesn't work for me:

$ podman run --rm -it -v /mnt/data:/mnt/data --userns=keep-id ubuntu
(container) # whoami
ubuntu
(container) # groups
ubuntu
(container) # ls -lah /mnt
drwxrwx---    nobody nogroup     data

I've become a different user now and I still don't have the group I need.

Likely duplicate of mount read-only host directory with only group access. I also tried --gidmap to map my local comp group to the container root group:

$ id -u
1000
$ getent group comp 
1003
$ podman run --rm -it -v /mnt/data:/mnt/data --uidmap=0:1000:1 --gidmap=0:1003:1 ubuntu
(container) # ls -lah /mnt
drwxrwx---    nobody nogroup     data
(container) # ls -lah /mnt/data
ls: cannot open directory '/mnt/data/': Permission denied


This is also mentioned on the Podman troubleshooting page. Here they suggest the :Z and :z volume option, but that also doesn't make a difference.


I've found a little bit of a solution, by using keep-groups:
$ podman run --rm -it -v /mnt/data:/mnt/data --userns=keep-id --group-add=keep-groups ubuntu
(container) # whoami
ubuntu
(container) # groups
ubuntu nogroup
(container) # id -u
1000
(container) # id -g 
1000
(container) # getent group nogroup
nogroup:x:65534:
(container) # ls -lah /mnt
drwxrwx---   nobody nogroup        data
(container) # ls -lah /mnt/data
-rw-rw-r--   ubuntu ubuntu         file.txt

Now it looks like I made by container user a member of nogroup, which is not what I expected when I'm trying to let my host user/group fall through into the container.
And this is not a real solution to me, as the functionality of my real image breaks with this nogroup.

This does not seem to be answer, see: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

My question was how avoid the 'permission denied' issue. My post above shows how to that: for the first time I could actually read the content of /mn/data. But it has a weird side-effect. It makes it an imperfect answer, but an answer nonetheless.
